# Executing REDIS Command in Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

I am writing a Node app. This app interacts with a REDIS database. To do that, I'm using [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). Sometimes, I want to just execute a command using a line of text. In other words, I want to do a pass through without using the wrapper functions. For instance, I may have:

```
set myKey myValue
```

I would LOVE to be able to just execute that without having to break apart the text and call client.set('mykey', 'myValue'); Is there a way to just execute a command like that against REDIS in the Node world? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `client.send_command(command_name, args, callback)` to send arbitrary commands to redis.  Args can be empty and so in your case you would just call `client.send_command('set myKey myValue', null, cb)`.

Comment: But when I am using the same command, I am getting an error - "Cannot read property 'length' of null"